# How do i make a manually added value in a choice column persist

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint list with a "Choice" with "Can add values manually" checked.

How do i make a manually added value in a choice column persist so that is available when adding and editing other records?

Comment: they are persisted whenever you add/edit an item. After that when you create a new item or edit it, they will be available.

Comment: unfortunately they are not...

Comment: that's quite strange, you actually dont have to do anything. Its just handled by SharePoint itself.

Comment: I wish that was the case... maybe there is another setting somewhere. thanks for replying so quickly anyhow.

Comment: can you create a new test list with the same settings and check ? Could be that the issue is present in the list itself ?

Comment: already tried with an exising list and a brand new test one - with edit and add... the existing manually added values are not included in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I created new list on my Office365 SharePoint site. When in classic mode, manually entered values are not available while editing/creating new list items regardless the choices are displayed in a dropdown, radio buttons or as multi select checkboxes. When switching from classic to modern SharePoint experience, manually entered values are available while editing/adding list items. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: The choices highlighted at the bottom are the one added manually via the 'fill-in' choices.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the same behaviour we are seeing on our side...